# Making a favourites list

Tags: iphone, image

I have a background app, where you can brows trough all kinds of backgrounds.
I also want to have a favourites list.
But when you are in a (n arbitrary) background view controller, and you press the favourite icon, how do I implement that when the button is pressed in the viewcontroller of the background, then it will be displayed in the favourites viewcontroller?

So in short, when you tap the favourite icon in a background, the favourites list will display this image in it.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm only 14 and new to this....
The only thing I need to know is how you can call a IBAction from the backgrounds viewcontroller to "say" to the favourites view controller that this specific backgrounc is favourited

Comment: I remember being 14 and learning to program. It's tough. That was on a C64, with no Internet. :) Still, StackOverflow is not for these kinds of questions. Read these: http://stackoverflow.com/faq http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: oh i'm sorry, do you know where I can go with my questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a boolean condition for when the favorites condition is pressed/not pressed and determine to show it on the other view controller. This is just one way, there are other ways im sure you can explore also. Have fun coding!